# How to merge these two array?

Tags: php, arrays

These are my two arrays:

```
$test = array(
    "0" => array(
        "mem_id" => "299", 
        "profilenam" => "Guys&Dolls", 
        "photo_b_thumb" => "photos/935a89f58ef2f3c7aaaf294cb1461d64bth.jpeg"
    ), 
    "1" => array(
        "mem_id" => "344", 
        "profilenam" => "Dmitry", 
        "photo_b_thumb" => "no")
    );

$distance = array(
    "0" => "0", 
    "1" => "3.362", 
    "2" => "0.23"
);
```

I want to combine them as:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [mem_id] => 299
            [profilenam] => Guys&Dolls
            [photo_b_thumb] => photos/935a89f58ef2f3c7aaaf294cb1461d64bth.jpeg
            [distance] => 3.362
         )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [mem_id] => 344
            [profilenam] => Dmitry
            [photo_b_thumb] => no
            [distance] => 0.23
        )

)
```

I tried the code below but it did not work:

```
foreach ($test as $key => $value) {
    $merged = array_merge((array) $value, $distance);
}
print_r($merged);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php

    foreach($test as $index=>$array)
    {
         $test[$index]['distance'] = $distance[$index]
    }

    print_r($test);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$test = array("0" => array("mem_id" => "299", "profilenam" => "Guys&Dolls", "photo_b_thumb" => "photos/935a89f58ef2f3c7aaaf294cb1461d64bth.jpeg"
    ), "1" => array("mem_id" => "344", "profilenam" => "Dmitry", "photo_b_thumb" => "no"));

$distance = array("0" => "0", "1" => "3.362", "2" => "0.23");

foreach( $test as $id => $data ) {
    $test[$id]['distance'] = $distance[$id];
}
```

Something like this should work!

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($test as $key => &$value) {
  $value["distance"] = $distance[$key];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think [array_merge_recursive](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php) does what you need.

EDIT: It does not. :) However, a derivate of it, posted in the `array_map_recursive` man page does seem to, see [this codepad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/1gs6Dy). I'd be interested to know which is faster over a large dataset.

Comment: and how do you plan to use array merge recursive??? check [this codepad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/ZoXxO6)

Comment: Hmm you may be right. The way I had in my head was to run an array_map over the distance array to create an array along the lines of `array( [0] => array( [distance] => 0 ) ... );` then merge them, but this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: See my edit, the PHP inbuilt function didn't work as I thought (it didn't append the numeric keys as I imagined it would having read the man-page), but some user-contributed code does work.

Answer (score -1):

```
foreach ($test as &$value)
{
   $value['distance'] = array_shift($distance);
}
```